# Google REST API Download

Tags: vb.net, download, google-drive-api

I am struggling with getting data from Google Drive.

I am using Google Drive API v3 with this code:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text

Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v3
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Util.Store


Public Class DownloadMe
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn0_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn0.Click
        DownloadMe()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DownloadMe()
        Dim fileID As String = "someFileID"
        Dim driveService As New DriveService
        Dim request = driveService.Files.Export(fileID, "text/plain")
        'Dim request = driveService.Files.Get(fileID)

        Dim dir As String = "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\GoogleDriveDownload\"
        Dim output As String = dir + "test.txt"
        Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream

        Try
            request.Download(stream)
            If System.IO.File.Exists(output) Then
                System.IO.File.Delete(output)
            End If

            Dim fs As New FileStream(output, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
            stream.WriteTo(fs)

            stream.Close()
            fs.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MyCompany.Diagnostics.Log("An error occured: " + ex.Message)
            lit0.Text = "An error occured: " + ex.Message + "<br />"
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is I am getting nothing in the stream, so the created "text.txt" file is a blank file instead of the typical "Lorem ipsum..." text.

Any clue on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Service3 = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = credential, .ApplicationName = "Google Drive VB Dot Net"})

Dim fileId = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
Dim request = Service3.Files.Get(fileId)
Dim Results = request.Execute

'Dim Stream2 = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
Dim Filename = "C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\Downloads\" & Results.Name
Using FileStream = New System.IO.FileStream(Filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
    request.Download(FileStream)
End Using
```